# Mocking an external call to TwitterAPI Client in rails with Rspec.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, stubbing

I'm trying to mock this call in my tests for an model method:

```
    client = TwitterAPI.new.client
```

I'm not sure how to do this in tests, as I've tried

```
allow_any_instance_of(TwitterAPI::Client).to receive(:search).with(@search, @since_time, @until_time).and_return(unprocessed_tweets(3, @tag_name, @now-1.weeks, @now))
```

But this gives me a name error, and I feel like, regardless is the incorrect approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a name error because TwitterAPI::Client does not exist. What you could do is stub responses when you send the `:new` and `:client` messages to `TwitterAPI`, with the latter returning a double that responds to `:search`.

With that said, why not have a TwitterClient class that returns a client when you instantiate an object from it? `TwitterAPI.new.client` seems awkward.

Comment: Could you give me a code example of what you mean in the second part? /